# eclipse add jni and .jar libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface

I am doing a program in java which collects information from a serial port and sends it over the network.

The network packets are somewhat special and  I need send the packets with rawMac format. For that I used the Java Native Interface (JNI).

I've done two modules and operate separately. 
- To network module, I must put into the VM arguments  "-Djava.library.path = jni" for the ejecution.
-For the modul serial I use the RXTXcomm.jar I put it in the Build Path.

When I put together, if I put "-Djava.library.path = jni" the RXTX isn't recognized and if I do not put "-Djava.library.path = jni" the program not find the libraries that I created with JNI

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new Jar Library to your Project you must go to the Navigation List. There you can make a right click with the mouse on the Project-Folder. There is the Option Build Path, there you can add Jars...

Comment: I know, I usually work this way. The problem is when I try use a my own JNI library at same time.

If I use the JNI library I have this error: "no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver"

If I don't use the VM arguments "-Djava.library.path = jni" I have this error: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no IN_SAP_write in java.library.path"